# Calcuating percentage error of percentage

Tags: education, percentages

I have a fundamental question regarding calculation of percentage error

In the graph below, there is a calculation about what percentage of population needs to be vaccinated in order to prevent a potential third wave of COVID19

So, the target is 7 %, and currently vaccinated percentage is 4 %. So, in my opinion the shortfall is 3 % from target. However, in the graph below it has been calculated as 41 % (4-7 / 7 )

So, my question is which is correct. 3 % or 41 %, and why ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is easier if we consider a real value problem.

Suppose that there is a price drop of 3D (D for dollar) of an item. How "big" is the saving?

If the original price is 7D and it has been cut down to 4D, the saving of 3D is quite "large" because we have only spent 4D for that item.

But, what if the item was 10007D originally, and the discounted price is 10004D. The saving is also 3D, ***provided that we have spent 10004D***.

That is why we need to use the **percentage change formula** to make a ***relative*** comparison.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand you point of view, but in this case where I the vaccination target and current vaccination is indicated in terms of percentage of population, isn't a direct mathematical subtraction a more reasonable way to compare

If we change the target to : 20 % of population
and current vaccinated to : 17 % of population
The percentage lag is still : 3 % of population

Comment: @MasoomKumar Your point is looking at the matter from another angle. However, percentage change is the commonly accepted method in making comparison.